# Use artifact outside of maven

Tags: maven

Well, this is kind of embarrassing.  I am in the process of mavenizing our build processes and just don't know how the access the result of a build.  I build, let's say, a jar file and `mvn deploy` it.  So it ends up as some `blah-0.1.2.jar` in our company maven repository, which is just a webdav share. Now how would you pass that on to someone else to use?  Just pry it from `target/blah-0.1.2.jar` can't be the answer.  I found several suggestions to use variants of `mvn dependency:get` but they were all just close and didn't feel right.  There must be a way to use all those nice versions of blah-*.jar that end up in the repository for purposes other than a maven dependency. Preferably from the command line and maybe even without maven. Hm, a webdav client doesn't look too bad except for snapshots.  What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a script that makes a `dependency:get` call is probably going to be closest to your desired outcome. You can specify the destination of your downloaded jar this way.

If you are looking for an easy way to share builds between people in/outside of your company then you can look into setting up some automated build software like [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo) or something similar. A new build gets triggered any time a commit is made to the section where your project resides in whatever version control system you use. An artifact is then made available for each successful build and are available via Bamboo's web interface. Bamboo can be configured to run with your maven pom's.

While they can bit a bit of pain to set up, going the automated build route will take a lot of the sting out of sharing your builds in the future.